# filter files that starts with dot in your name (regular expression, elfinder + codeigniter)

Tags: codeigniter, filter, connector, elfinder

I have searched some topics here about my question but I haven't found or some didn't work for me.

I am using elfinder in codeigniter then in the connector file I need to filter the file names that begins with dot caracter. I would like do this because the filemanager shows the .tmb (thumbnails) folder and I don't want... I only would like to filter all filenames that starts with a dot:

.tmb
.htaccess
.folder
.file
.any file or folder

I have tried a lot of regular expression ('pattern' => '/^TEST$/') but It didn't work for me.

Thank you!

```
    public function elfinder_init(){
    if ($this->session->userdata('name')) {

        $ruta = trim($this->input->get("path"));

        $opts = array(
             //'debug' => true,
                'roots' => array(
                            array(
                                'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem',
                                'path'   => set_realpath($ruta),
                                'URL'    => site_url($ruta) . "/",
                                'accessControl' => 'access',
                                'defaults' => array('read' => true, 'write' => true),
                                'encoding' => '',
                                'attributes' => array(
                                        array(
                                                'pattern' => '/^TEST$/',
                                                'hidden' => true,
                                                'read'    => true,
                                                'write'   => true,
                                                'locked'  => false
                                        )
                                )
                                // more elFinder options here
                            )
                )
        );



        $this->load->library('elfinder_lib', $opts);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found one way to hide the thumbnails folder using the next pattern:

```
'pattern' => '/\.tmb$/',
```

Although I think that the best way is using other pattern for all filenames that begins for dot and not only the .tmb folder...

I also have tried using the next code in a php file:

```
if (preg_match("/^\./", ".tmb")) 
    echo "The name has a dot";
else
    echo "The name hasn't dot";
```

It worked fine... why didn't work in the pattern? I don't understand this... xd